# What font is used in criticalstack.com logo?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification, font-recommendation

What font is used in this logo? I'd love to use this font in my company logo.

I have attempted to find the font using all the tools those which have stated in the guidelines page. But I couldn't find the exact font. I have attached a logo sample from the original website and it's called criticalstack.com.

The closest match whatismyfont.com provided is 'Mirai Thin' font.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On their website they are using a font directly for the logo (it is not an image):

```
span.header-logotext-c-dark {
 font-family: mirai-regular;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #fff;
}

span.header-logotext-s-dark {
 font-family: mirai-light;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: .8;
}
```

That font is definitely [Mirai Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/gtandcanary/mirai/regular/) for the word "Critical" and [Mirai Light](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/gtandcanary/mirai/light/) for the word "stack".

**UPDATE:**

Fascinatingly they are apparently using a modified version in the image you provided. I'm not sure why they would represent their logo in two different ways, but, as pointed out in comments, the image version is modified significantly:

[image]

I'll leave my answer, and we'll pretend you asked what the logo on the website is! ;)

**Another update after some more, let's say constructive, comments:**

My best answer is that your image represents a custom typeface, very likely made by adapting Myrai.

Comment: This isn't completely accurate. While it might be the base font the r is HEAVILY modified and the whole text has a rounded/bold effect to it.

Comment: While this may be correct for the current logo the font does not match. Even with heavy editing (rounding+strokes) the curves and size don't match up. He's asking about the picture not the current logo.

Comment: Try showing the images superimposed, the way you have it is not a useful comparision https://imgur.com/a/2WRkv

Comment: thanks for the answer by the way. but what i'm looking for is the image i have attached and i tried every single way possible. i did a search called mirai alternatives and checked the list as well. but there were nothing that could solve my question. i guess i will have to contact them and ask, may be they won't hesitate to let me know about the font that they were using in the old logo.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I have showed it superimposed already, and I left my answer because its interesting, took some effort and it clearly represents both the base font. It also illustrates that this company themselves think that Mirai is close enough to use a font in their logo. Plus, get of my case and have a go yourself.

Comment: @mayersdesign Your answer is the same core but you should be clearer on the differentiations from the current logo vs the one he's trying to match. This is simply a matter of answer completeness.